# What was Draco's motive that he summoned a snake in the duel?

Tags: harry-potter

I mean, there's many other spells he could've cast, but why choose to launch a snake of all things?

Comment: It was Snape's idea. Now why *Snape* thought it was a good idea - that I can't tell you.

Comment: To scare Harry?

Comment: @Mithrandir Voted to leave open: the answer to the old question is "we don't know Snape told him to use a snake specifically", which doesn't answer this at all.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It seems dupey to me. The other answer indicates that he didn't expect Harry to be able to deal with it the snake. He was going to 'get rid of it' for him and then presumably declare Malfoy the winner.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - At the very least, any new evidence on the subject would absolutely answer the other question so there's little point having two almost-identical questions about the motives behind one spell being used in one book.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, but none of that answers why *Malfoy* chose to use the snake. Let's say the old answer is right and Snape didn't tell him anything so specific; then the question of why he used a snake specifically is still open and independent. (I also thought they were dupes based on the titles, but then looked further and realised they aren't.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor -  The implication is that he was **told to use that spell by Snape** (who expected that Harry wouldn't be able to counter it or deal with the consequences thus giving Malfoy a duel-winning spell to play with).

Comment: @Valorum No, the implication of [the answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/180398/31394) is that **Snape probably didn't tell him to use that spell**, maybe just giving him some general advice. Which leaves open the question of why Malfoy decided to use a *snake* of all things.

Comment: I was just thinking, as that was the first time Harry was 'exposed' as a parsel mouth then parseltongue turns out to be super useful later throughout the book as he gets closer to opening the chamber of secrets. From what I understand, if Harry didn't have that experience in with Draco's snake, he probably wouldn't have figured out that's how to open the chamber of secrets.

Answer (score 3):

The premise of this question may be flawed. You ask why Malfoy used a snake-summoning-spell rather than any other spell. But wouldn't you have the same question if he had used any other spell? If he had summoned a different animal you could ask why he did specifically that. If he had used the Bat-Bogey Hex you could ask why he specifically used that. No matter what he would have used, there would be other spells that he didn't use.<sup>1</sup>

Whenever something has to be chosen out of a group of possibilities, there will by definition be other possibilities that were not chosen. Even if all of the possibilities have equal reason to be chosen, only one of them can be chosen. That means that it is possible for something to be chosen without there being a specific reason for it being a better choice than the other candidates.

Since there is not much information in the book surrounding Malfoy's choice of spell, we don't really know why he chose it. It might have simply been the first spell that popped into his head (or Snape's head, if that's what Snape whispered to him) or one of the few spells he was capable of performing. Of course, for plot reasons it was important for Malfoy to use this spell, but from Malfoy's own perspective we simply don't have a basis to assume that there was much of a strategic reason in the first place.

---

<sup>1. As the medieval philosopher [Gersonides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) wrote in the introduction to his book of philosophy (translated by Seymour Feldman):</sup>

> <sup>Hence the reader should not inquire concerning these things why we have treated this thing before some other thing, since [he thinks] that the other thing should be treated first because of one of the aforementioned reasons. We have in fact treated one particular subject first precisely because of one of these reasons: and it is obvious that if we had adopted the reverse order the same question would have been raised.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Er, why cast a cool and showy spell in front of the whole school, you ask? Being awesome needs no reason.

And, in spite of Harry's perspective, Justin was never in any danger -- Snape, like everyone else, was surprised by *Harry's* unexpected response to Lockhart's unexpected attack on the snake.

One it was clear that Harry was done speaking a rare language and *not* aiming to do anything else, only then did Snape tend to the simple expedient of dispatching the patiently calm animal with a quick puff of smoke.

Comment: Are there no other "cool and showy spells"?

Comment: @Alex Draco is a Slytherin, and proud of it.  He's facing off against Harry Potter, with whom he has a rivalry, who is a Gryffindor, with whom Slytherin house have a rivalry.  It's not just "cool and showy", it's "cool, showy and *symbolic*".  Which makes Harry then responding with Parseltongue quite the slap in the face.

Comment: @Chronocidal But that’s not what this answer says.

Comment: @Alex This answer says "he used a showy spell".  Yes, there are undoubtedly *other* showy spells, but I was giving reasoning why Draco might have learned and used this **particular** showy spell

Comment: @Chronocidal I understand. But my question is on *this* answer which doesn’t give a reason for this particular showy spell.

Comment: @Alex Er, no, that is _exactly_ what this answer says. We cannot answer why precisely Draco/Snape chose this _particular_ spell over any other cool spell. Presumably it is one that Draco knows, and a good one to show up that poser Harry Potter. _This_ answer says: “Draco chose _this_ spell because it is awesome.” Of _course_ there are other awesome spells. Draco knows this one, it’s pretty impressive for a second-year, snakes are cool and scary, it’ll show up Harry... beyond that we are treading in places only God/The Universe knows.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I don't see where your answer says that.

Comment: @Alex Um, the first two sentences?

You seem to be trying to get me to say something beyond the idea that this _particular_ spell’s choice has no _particular_ reason, other than the Rule Of Cool.

Comment: @Dúthomhas The first two sentences only mention that the spell was used because it was cool, but not any of the additional information in your comments.

Answer (score -1):

Out-of-universe, it was clearly to lead to revealing that Harry was a Parselmouth. In-universe, the Malfoys are a Slytherin family (and the mascot of Slytherin is a snake), and are fond of reptilian imagery. Lucius has a snake head on his cane, the family crest has two dragons and two snakes, "Draco" is from the Latin for dragon, etc.